# Adding elements into an array using loop Python

Tags: python, arrays

I just started learning python and I was wondering how I can add a digit into an array using a loop

eg: 1234 into [1][2][3][4]

Am i doing something wrong?

```
x = len(str(user))
num_array = []
for i in range (0, x):
   num_array.append[i] = number % 10 //  ??
   number /= 10
```

this is how I would write it in c.

```
  for (i=0; i < integer_size; i++)
  {
    splitArray[i] = integer % 10;
    integer /= 10;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example output doesn't make any sense and isn't valid. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for a list comprehension? Or just `user.split()`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Looks like OP is trying to convert an integer `1234` to list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Your example code *would* (if it was valid Python syntax) create the list `[4, 3, 2, 1]` and not `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You should also use `//=` if using Python 3.

Comment: Oh ok i got it to work. i'll just reverse the array. thanks

Comment: Why not just `print([int(i) for i in str(user)])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `split` method from python, below code is valid for both `python2.7` & `python3`.Take a look at [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
number = 1234
result = [x for x in str(number)]
```

Testing

```
>>> d = 1234
>>> [int(x) for x in str(d)]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: Alternatively, `list(map(int, str(d)))`, or just `map(int, str(d))` in Python 2.